# Create Constraint neo4j Error

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-bolt

I am trying to improve the query performance by creating the constraint on a property of a node. But, I am ending up with the following error. It mostly looks like a python error. I am using Neo4j bolt driver.

I am creating the constraints in a session and then I am pushing the nodes as a Batch.

My code:

```
session = driver.session()
session.run('CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (u:user) ASSERT u.user IS UNIQUE')
session.run('CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (h:hobby) ASSERT h.hobby IS UNIQUE')

session.close()

def writeBatch(b):
    print("writing batch of " + str(len(b)))
    session = driver.session()
    session.run('UNWIND {batch} AS elt '+
                'MERGE (u:user{user: elt.user})'+
                'MERGE (h:hobby{hobby:elt.hobby})'+
                'MERGE (u)-[r:hobby]->(h)'
                +'', {'batch': b})
    session.close()

writeBatch(b)
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adaggula/Documents/workspace2/Facebook/FbNeo.py", line 145, in <module>
    userhobby.foreach(write2neo)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 747, in foreach
    self.mapPartitions(processPartition).count()  # Force evaluation
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1004, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 995, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 869, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2379, in _jrdd
    pickled_cmd, bvars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(self.ctx, command, self)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2299, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 428, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 646, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 107, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 633, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 199, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 236, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 193, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 241, in save_function_tuple
    save(f_globals)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 193, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 241, in save_function_tuple
    save(f_globals)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 686, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 524, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 686, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 542, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 315, in save_builtin_function
    return self.save_function(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 191, in save_function
    if islambda(obj) or obj.__code__.co_filename == '<stdin>' or themodule is None:
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'
16/09/20 16:35:22 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: Your stack trace contains errors from std lib and pyspark. There seems to be no relation to the code/problem you posted.

Comment: I did not exactly understand your point. Can you please elaborate your point. So that I can look into that.

Comment: When the create constraints are commented then the code working fine

Comment: The thing is, the call to `session.run()` which supposedly causes the exception does not appear in the stack trace, so it's hard to see how they are related.